# Gson mapping 2 different class fields Mongo DB point into LatLng class

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

Is there a simple way to map 2 different classes fields? I'm using point class from mongoDB to have a longitude and latitude, sending these points to an android app as JSON and would like to map the values inside this JSON to a different fields names that exist in the LatLng class.

To make it simple:

```
public class a {

  String x;
  String y;
}

public class b {

  String a;
  String b;
}
```

Sending class a as JSON to an application, in the application i cant have class a but would like to map the JSON like that:

```
class a.x -> class b.a
class a.y -> class b.b
```

is it possible to use GSON to have above logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the name the JSON is using in a [SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

```
public class b {

  @SerializedName("x")
  String a;

  @SerializedName("y")
  String b;

}
```

Although, it might be worthwhile changing the server to return a more readable type.